# getItemValueInteger exception message

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

OpenLogger is giving the me the following error:

> Expression Language Interpret Exception Error:Method
>   NotesXspDocument.getItemValueInteger(number) not found, or illegal
>   parameters - Error on chkReview:
>
> Interpret exception
>
> Error:Method NotesXspDocument.getItemValueInteger(number) not found,
>   or illegal parameters

The component chkReview only has 2 lines where getItemValueInteger is used, which is on the onClick event (single checkbox):

```
var reviewField:string = "numberOfReviewQuestions"+compositeData.reviewTeam;
var currentNumberReview = document1.getItemValueInteger(reviewField);   
var sectionReview:string = compositeData.section + compositeData.reviewTeam;    
var currentNumberSection = document1.getItemValueInteger(sectionReview);
```

compositeData.reviewTeam & compositeData.section both return a string. As such, I'm not sure if I have tunnel vision or not, however, I can't see what's wrong with my code? Can anyone point in the right direction? Stack trace below if this helps, and full onClick code also, thanks:

```
try{
    var strCurrVal = getComponent('txtReviewSummary').getValue();
    var strNewVal ="";
    var strText ="";
    var dt = new Date();
    var strUser = userBean.getDisplayName();
    var reviewField:string = "numberOfReviewQuestions"+compositeData.reviewTeam;
    var currentNumberReview = document1.getItemValueInteger(reviewField);   
    var sectionReview:string = compositeData.section + compositeData.reviewTeam;    
    var currentNumberSection = document1.getItemValueInteger(sectionReview);

if (getComponent('chkReview').getValue() == "true") {
    // checkbox selected - do something
    var dateTimeFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm");
    var dateTimeString = dateTimeFormat.format(dt);
    var strReview = " - [Review] - ("+dateTimeString+" - " + strUser + ")";
    strNewVal = strCurrVal+strReview;
    strText = "Review complete for " + compositeData.fieldName;
    document1.replaceItemValue(reviewField, currentNumberReview-1); 
} else {
    // checkbox not selected- do something else
    strNewVal = @Left(strCurrVal, " - [Review]");
    strText = "Removed review for " + compositeData.fieldName + ". Previous value was: " + strNewVal;
    document1.replaceItemValue(reviewField, currentNumberReview+1); 
}

var arrNotes:array = AddNoteItem(currentDocument, dt, strText, strUser);
document1.replaceItemValue(concatReviewSummary, strNewVal);
document1.save();

}catch(e){
    openLogBean.addError(e,this.getParent());
}


> com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Interpret exception at
> com.paulwithers.openLog.OpenLogErrorHolder.getInterpretException(OpenLogErrorHolder.java:114)
> at
> com.paulwithers.openLog.OpenLogErrorHolder.addError(OpenLogErrorHolder.java:216)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) at
> com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:322)
> at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161) at
> com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197) at
> com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpretCatch(ASTTry.java:150) at
> com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:113) at
> com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119) at
> com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139) at
> com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
> at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424) at
> com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414) at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:730)
> at
> com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
> at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
> at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
> at
> com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)
> at
> com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111)
> at
> com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:60)
> at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324) at
> com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:366)
> at
> com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
> at
> com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
> at
> com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
> at
> com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
> at
> com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
> at
> com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1535)
> at
> javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307)
> at
> javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428)
> at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94)
> at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
> at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
> at
> com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
> at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:227)
> at
> com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
> at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:159) at
> com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138) at
> com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
> at
> com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:588)
> at
> com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
> at
> com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:865)
> at
> com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:808)
> at
> com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:577)
> at
> com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
> at
> com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
> at
> com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
> at
> com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
> at
> com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
> at
> com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
> Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Error:Method
> NotesXspDocument.getItemValueInteger(number) not found, or illegal
> parameters at
> com.paulwithers.openLog.OpenLogErrorHolder.getInterpretException(OpenLogErrorHolder.java:113)
> ... 52 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different take then Paul (although he may be correct), XPage runtime is interpreting the composition of reviewField or sectionReview as a number, and attempting to find a method "getItemValueInteger" that runs using a numeric parameter.

I'd focus in on this:

```
var sectionReview:string = compositeData.section + compositeData.reviewTeam;
```

as the other seems to be unambiguously a String; good to remember that the ":string" are hints but not contracts, so you might want to coerce the composition of compositeData.section and compositeData.reviewTeam into a string, to be certain.

Example:

```
var reviewField:string = "numberOfReviewQuestions"+compositeData.reviewTeam;
var currentNumberReview = document1.getItemValueInteger(@Text(reviewField));
var sectionReview:string = compositeData.section + compositeData.reviewTeam;    
var currentNumberSection = document1.getItemValueInteger(@Text(sectionReview));
```

I'm drawn to this approach as for me, when compositeData is unavailable, I get null pointer exceptions, not data type errors, in similar structures. Similarly, if document1 is unavailable or uninitialized, the error is generally not a method invocation error, but that document1 is null or not an object.

Comment: Thanks, I may try this tomorrow - One thing to note, var sectionReview:string = compositeData.section + compositeData.reviewTeam; seems to work as expected though, as the field is stored on my document, for example "section3PITeam" and also stores a number, the field type being number/integer. It also doesnt seem to stop anything from happening on my xpage, as in, everything still seems to work, whilst it logs the error

Comment: Could be a bad "state" during a single particular segment of the lifecycle -- which would imply some blend of my and Paul's answer. Def been burned by this. Many things get run multiple times during page render and recomputes, and not all variables are available during every cycle. I often wrap executions that "mutate" the document so that they will only run once during computation (viewScope or requestScope latch, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's a timing issue. The assumption is false that everything on your XPage is processed in a single pass, so if it's on the XPage, it must exist. The `compositeData` variable probably hasn't been set at the time you're trying to use it. Confirm that by printing out the value. The other scenario, less likely, is `document1` hasn't been initialised yet. Again, you can check that in your code by calling a standard non-parameterised method (`getNoteID()` may work).